# Getting ag-grid's postSortRows to work with loadash's sortBy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash, ag-grid-vue

I'm suing `ag-grid-vue` to work with a dataset and would like to get the rows to be grouped by a certain value of field `status` that I provide using an array with the order I want. So, following [the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/row-sorting/#post-sort), inside the `created()` hook I'm using:

```js
created() {
  this.postSortRows = (params) => {
    var rowNodes = params.nodes;

    const order = ['Atrasado', 'Pendente', 'Pronto', 'Entregue'];

    rowNodes = _.sortBy(rowNodes, function(obj) {
      return _.indexOf(order, obj.data.status);
    });
  //prints an empty array AND the the desired sorted array.
  console.log(rowNodes);

  }
```

But the problem with this is that the `_.sortBy` function is behaving asynchronously and if I try to console.log the value of `rowNodes` after the assignment, it prints two times:
[image]

But the rows keep unsorted.

From the docs, this piece of code works:

```js
let nextInsertPos = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < rowNodes.length; i++) {
  const status = rowNodes[i].data.status;
  if (status === 'Atrasado') {
    rowNodes.splice(nextInsertPos, 0, rowNodes.splice(i, 1)[0]);
    nextInsertPos++;
  }
}
```

I checked the lodash docs and it doesn't say that the return value of the `_.sortBy` function is asynchronous, but it also does not say the opposite. I already tried to wrap the contents of the created hook  inside another function and using a second argument as callback function, but it doesn't work either. Is there anything special to get this working? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that the problems was in the assignment I was making to the ag-grid variable holding rowNodes. Solved by, instead of directly assigning the value of sortBy, using `Object.assign`:

```
const sorted = _.sortBy(rowNodes, function(obj) {
  const val =  _.indexOf(order, obj.data.status);
  return _.indexOf(order, obj.data.status);
});
Object.assign(rowNodes, sorted);
```